# Prescribed class of measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X\neq\emptyset$ and let $\mu:P(X)\to[0,\infty]$  be an outer measure. Recall that, a set $A\subseteq X$ is $\mu$-measurable if
$$
\mu(B)=\mu(A\cap B)+\mu(B\setminus A), \text{ for all }B\subseteq X.
$$
Let $M(X,\mu):=\{A\subseteq X:A\text { is }\mu-\text{measurable}\}$ be the set of all $\mu$-measurable sets. We know that $M(X,\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

**QUESTION:**

My question is about the converse. Given any $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, does there exist an outer measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that
$$
\boxed{\sigma=M(X,\mu)?}
$$
If not, is there any necessary and sufficient condition on $\sigma$ that ensures the existence of an outer measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that $
\sigma=M(X,\mu)?
$

Comment: The constructed measure will be complete. So the Borel sets on the real line are a counterexample.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thank you for your comments. How do we know that the set of all Borel sets on R is not complete with respect to some outer measure? What we know is that it is not complete with respect to the Lebsegue measure.

Comment: There are results about such spaces that imply there will be an uncountable Borel set with measure zero, at least under a $\sigma$-finite measure. An uncountable Borel set has the cardinality of the continuum. Butany more subsets.

Comment: And there are only continuum many Borel sets.

Comment: Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/87838/1946